# Script to find out incorrect merges between branches in GIT

Tags: git, git-bash

I am looking for shell/bash/powershell script which can detect incorrect merge order between branches and display some output to alert.

Assuming there are branches A,B,C and D.The order of merge should always be in one direction Example A-->B, A-->C, A-->D, B-->C, B-->D etc. The merge between two branches should not happen in the reverse order example C-->B, D-->A, etc

I have used git branch --list -a --A to get the list of branches merged into a particular branch

Expecting an Alert message on script execution to detect if merges happened in incorrect order.

Comment: If the branch names are not obvious (e.g., are foo, bar, baz, and quux rather than the obviously pre-sorted A,B,C,D), how do you know whether foo->bar and/or baz->quux are correct or incorrect?

Comment: If e.g., foo, bar, baz, and quux are the branches then  deployment date defines the order so foo gets deployed first then bar, then baz, then quux.

Comment: I don't see how anything called "deployment date" is identified here. Each Git commit has two time stamps. Branch names are just pointers, pointing to commits. One can re-point any of these pointers to any existing commit at any time. The commits themselves are fixed/permanent/frozen-for-all-time, so it seems likely that your goal is accomplish-able, but I don't know how to map moveable, changeable branch *names* into this picture.